# PHP - Send mail with gmail XOAUTH2 - get_oauth_token in production

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, gmail, phpmailer

I've successfully sent mail using PHPMailer, gmail and XOAUTH2 from my localhost. Now I need to publish my site in production.

From google console there is the "Publish App" button, that is working only if URI and redirect URI are in https.

My question is: the get_oauth_token.php file, that permits to generate a refresh token, must be uploaded in the production website?
In my opition this does not make sense, because that's a public page and when you click on "Publish app" on GCP it says "Will be accessible by any gmail account". But it seems to be the only solution to use gmail in production.

It is possible to:

- upload the page
- generate the refresh token
- remove the page

?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Redirect URI is the location which the authorization server returns your authorization code.  It must be HTTPS it can not be localhost.     Its location should be where ever your production app is running from.    Im not sure why you would want to remove the page no one will be able to authorize your application if you remove it.

Comment: Technically it can work with localhost because it redirects your browser to that location, which you can of course access since it's your machine. However, Google has added additional constraints such as the https requirement that make it more difficult. So upload it to a server with a certificate and do the auth from there. You should only need to do it once because you are the only one that needs to authorize it, so yes, you can remove the page after you've got the access and refresh tokens.

Comment: First of all thanks for answers. But i've not explained well.

the problem is: I need a refresh token to permit my backend to send email using my gmail account and oauth2 auth. I do not want to permit to any user to generate a refresh token. So the idea is: can I generate the refresh token (not from localhost) and then remove the get_oauth_token.php from the server? What are the consequences of leaving the page on a public site online?